# What does the constraint mean?

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL and I am trying to create a table with a constraint but I have not used the constrant before and I am not actually certain what this constraint does uc_ID on PId, LastName?

I want to create a constraint that will only allow alpha numeric values in a column?

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
 (
 PId   int   identity(1,1)       NOT NULL,
 LastName           varchar(25)  NOT NULL,
 FirstName          varchar(25)  NOT NULL,
 Address1           varchar(25)  NOT NULL,
 City               varchar(25) NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT uc_ID UNIQUE (PId,LastName)
 )

CREATE TABLE E
 (
 PId            int identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
 LastName           varchar (25)  NOT NULL,
 FirstName          varchar (25)  NOT NULL,
 Address1           varchar (25)  NOT NULL,
 City               varchar (25)  NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT OnlyAlphanumeric CHECK ([FirstName] NOT LIKE '%[^A-Z0-9]%')
 )
```

Another Example (is not):

```
CREATE TABLE EEE
 (
 PId            int identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
 FirstName          varchar (50)  NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT CHECK ([FirstName]    LIKE '%[A-Za-z]%')
 )
```

Comment: It seems a pretty useless Constraint though :)

Comment: Probably is but it was just an example. I thought in the test that it would make the LastName have to be unique but it does not for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a constraint that allows only alphanumeric characters in a column you can use this (for example for `FirstName`:

```
ALTER TABLE [Persons] ADD CONSTRAINT OnlyAlphanumeric CHECK ([FirstName] NOT LIKE '%[^A-Z0-9 ]%')
```

Disclaimer: [taken from here](http://sqlanddotnetdevelopment.blogspot.ro/2012/09/check-constraint-to-allow-alphabets-and.html) (and tested).

If you want the constraint to be added when the table is created:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
 (
 PId   int   identity(1,1)       NOT NULL,
 LastName           varchar(25)  NOT NULL,
 FirstName          varchar(25)  NOT NULL,
 Address1           varchar(25)  NOT NULL,
 City               varchar(25) NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT OnlyAlphanumeric CHECK ([FirstName] NOT LIKE '%[^A-Z0-9 ]%')
 )
```

Note that constraint names are unique per database.

Alternatively, you can create an `AFTER INSERT` and `AFTER UPDATE` trigger to make this validation, but a constraint works just fine in this case.

Comment: What if I want to add this one an actual table when I create it.

Comment: @user3376708: See updated answer. Basically the same with what you added in your question.

Comment: @user3376708: Update your question with the error, do not add it to my answer :).

Comment: Sorry I wanted to add this to mine and put it on yours. Do you want it taken down?

Comment: @user3376708: no problem, I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

Means that the combination of Pid + LastName must be unique.
Since Pid is an identity, in normal circumstances it cannot be duplicated, so that constraint seems somehow redudant.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ADD CONSTRAINT Only_Characters_And_Numbers CHECK ColumnName NOT LIKE '%[^A-Z0-9 ]%'
```

Comment: You should also post the source for that.